# pandas read multiple tables with different number of columns

Tags: python, pandas

My apologies if this sounds like a repeated question, I found a number of related posts on this topic but none seems to provide me a solution for my specific version.
I am trying to read a space separated tabular data file with two different tables that alternate throughout the file. Here is a sample

```
Test abc ...
Date xx/xx/xx

Timestep 0

    No. u              v           w           x 
    1   0.00E+00    0.00E+00    0.00E+00    0.00E+00
    9   0.00E+00    0.00E+00    0.00E+00    0.00E+00
    18  0.00E+00    0.00E+00    0.00E+00    -3.00000E+02
    27  0.00E+00    0.00E+00    0.00E+00    -3.00000E+02
    ....

    Timestep 0 (some more columns

    No. g              h           i       
    1   0.00E+00    0.00E+00    0.00E+00
    9   0.00E+00    0.00E+00    0.00E+00
    18  0.00E+00    0.00E+00    0.00E+00    
    27  0.00E+00    0.00E+00    0.00E+00    
    ......

Timestep 1

    No. u              v           w           x 
    1   0.00E+00    0.00E+00    0.00E+00    0.00E+00
    9   0.00E+00    0.00E+00    0.00E+00    0.00E+00
    18  0.00E+00    0.00E+00    0.00E+00    -3.00000E+02
    27  0.00E+00    0.00E+00    0.00E+00    -3.00000E+02
    ....

    Timestep 1 (some more columns)

    No. g              h           i       
    1   0.00E+00    0.00E+00    0.00E+00
    9   0.00E+00    0.00E+00    0.00E+00
    18  0.00E+00    0.00E+00    0.00E+00    
    27  0.00E+00    0.00E+00    0.00E+00    
    ......
```

And the above pattern repeats alternatively throughout the file. What is the best way to read this data into a pandas dataframe?

Comment: Could you maybe share a shorter version that reflects file pattern? Are these `(some more columns)` aligned with the others or is this how you have it?

Comment: The facetious answer is "with great difficulty". You will almost certainly have to carry out some preprocessing on this file to get it to a point where it can be easily ingested by Pandas. A good first step would probably be to read the file, split it on the regex `Timestep (\d+)*` and sequentially save every element from the split into a separate csv file. This would give you two files for every timestep, each of which you could probably read directly into Pandas if you gave it the right `header` parameter.

Comment: @zipa, not sure what you mean by column alignment but there are basically two tables with different number of columns and the tables are separated by some text in between. The same pattern repeats throughout. The number of rows, however, are the same for each table. Would be great if we could read the two tables in two separate data frames or concatenate the columns from two tables and read it as one data frame.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought to add my solution here, which is to:

1. first read the entire contents (table) with extra padded columns to cater for longer lines of text;
2. then iterate and read the two different tables (based on given number of rows) into two different data frames (skipping the header lines);
3. Finally drop the padded columns added in the first step and give columns the names.